# Help with refactoring jQuery menu

Tags: jquery, refactoring

```
    $('#menu > li').hover(function() {
        $(this).prev().addClass('nobg');
    }, function() {
        $(this).prev().removeClass('nobg');
    });
    $('#menu > li:has(.submenu)').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').children('ul').show();
        $(this).prev().addClass('nobg');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active').children('ul').hide();    
        $(this).prev().removeClass('nobg');
    });
```

.. works great but looks really ugly, is it possible to compress this in fewer lines?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Dont be so hard on yourself, thats pretty succinct IMO :)

Comment: Please post the html for this... I can verify a solution.

Comment: Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net with the smallest code needed to show your working menu?

Comment: I found the bug in the code, I copied "next" from jQuery example. Removed. See now.

Comment: Can you post an html example? I think I could come up with a pure css solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
$('#menu > li').hover(function () {
    $(this).prev().stop(true, true).toggleClass('nobg');
});
$('#menu > li:has(.submenu)').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active")
        .children('ul').stop(true, true).toggle();
});
```

Based on http://api.jquery.com/hover/ (last example).

The use of "stop" is to avoid problems like here http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hover-and-toggleclass-fail-at-speed

Leave me a comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, you might want to try removing "Stop" from the first method, because you don't do animation or anything that takes so long in there. And tell me how it goes

Comment: I found the bug in the code, I copied "next" from jQuery example. Removed. See now.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt this can't be done with just CSS... but...

"hover" has an overload that only takes one function, which will be called for both events. Also, you can use toggleClass instead of add and remove.

```
$('#menu > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('nobg');
});

$('#menu > li:has(.submenu)').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').children('ul').toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('nobg');
});
```

The above code probably wont work though, because you'll be calling the toggles twice for anything with a submenu... I would try it with the code below. Posting a jsfiddle with your current trial would be extremely helpful. I could verify that it works for your case :) Or just post the html.

```
$(('#menu > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').children('ul').toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('nobg');
});
```

In addition, couldn't your css determine the visibility of the child uls?

```
.active>ul
{
    display:list-item;
}
```

If so, you can get ride of ".children('ul').toggle()" all together.

Comment: @mellamokb Yes! Sorry about that :)

Comment: Almost works! :) the `$(this).prev().toggleClass('nobg');` inside the second function doesn't work though. Hm...

Comment: Yes, it does... but the it also works for the first function. Therefore, they cancel each other out. try it with the second code snipit above...

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto @xixonia's solution, you could split out the functions into separate functions like this code below (untested):

```
var nobgtoggle = function() { $(this).prev().toggleClass('nobg'); }
var submenutoggle = function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').children('ul').toggle();
    nobgtoggle();
};

$('#menu > li').hover(nobgtoggle);
$('#menu > li:has(.submenu)').hover(submenutoggle);
```